# Query Help to determine average price for products < 3

Tags: sql, sqlhelper

Hi I've been working on this query, and I can't quite figure out the where statement to show only the average price of products < 3

"List each Product Class, number of items in the class and the average Price (name this Avg_Price, Format $0.00) of the items in the class. List only those classes that have less than three (3) items"

This query shows me the results of the average prices of the products (results in image)
COLUMN Avg_Price FORMAT $999,999.00
SELECT Product_Class, COUNT(*), AVG(Price) AS Avg_Price
FROM Product
GROUP BY Product_Class;

[image]

I need help only showing the counts avg PRICE that is < 3

Comment: Homework or assgiment?

Answer (score 1):

Include  [**Having**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) at the end

```
  HAVING count(*) > 3
```